# Changing gnome-terminal color theme depending on running app

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

Is it possible to change color theme (or whole gnome-terminal profile) of terminal if for example Midnight Commander is started inside gnome-terminal? My aim is not to launch a new terminal window but to change color theme depending on launched app.

Comment: `mc` has a no color option, but this may be of interest to you as well: https://superuser.com/a/1323399/234051

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a shell function to use `setterm` (or the equivalent on your OS) to change the colors before the program is invoked, but there is no way to change the gnome-terminal profile from the command line (the title *can* be changed though).

Comment: This. Wrapping the desired in shell scripts that setterm the terminal then run the program is pretty much the only way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at this topic: https://askubuntu.com/questions/137706/gnome-terminal-and-solarized-theme-coloring-issue

I was looking for a way to solve this using dbus...